# Can we tell dbcc to ignore subnormal real values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dbcc

Currently dbcc DATA_PURITY complains about subnormal real values in some of my columns, such as 7.561407E-42. I would rather keep them in my tables, and ask dbcc to ignore them.

I am OK with the check on upper limit, and other checks on other column types. So I would rather keep running the utility, but have it stop complaining about legitimate very low values.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of `DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY` is to check the database for column values that are not valid or are out-of-range.

In sql server 2000, it was possible to store out-of-range values in columns of certain datatypes like Float,real, datetime, etc. But moving from SQL 2005 and up, SQL Server will flag out those out-of-range values as it follows [Single-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Check @PaulWhite's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11304219/1387418).

From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx) :

> DBCC CHECKDB detects columns with date and time values that are larger than or less than the acceptable range for the datetime data type; or decimal or approximate-numeric data type columns with scale or precision values that are not valid.

You must fix those errors reported as described in [KB923247](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923247).

Comment: I think dbcc could do better - subnormal real values are valid. As such, they should not be considered out of range.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov Seems like it as pointed out by PaulWhite. Also, agree that DBCC should not point out **subnormal** values as out-of-range. Also, the link that I referenced, you are the one who is the OP :-)